# Obtener un JSON de una consulta SQL en Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

tengo varias tablas con los siguientes datos:

```
| sonda | fecha                   | valor  |
+-------+-------------------------+--------+
| s1    | 2018-10-23 23:34:00.444 |  34.5  |
| s2    | 2018-10-23 23:34:00.444 |  4.5   |
| s3    | 2018-10-23 23:34:00.444 |  10.5  |
| s4    | 2018-10-23 23:34:00.444 |  5     |
| s1    | 2018-10-23 23:35:00.444 |  23.5  |
| s2    | 2018-10-23 23:35:00.444 |  44.5  |
| s3    | 2018-10-23 23:35:00.444 |  6.7   |
| s4    | 2018-10-23 23:35:00.444 |  13.4  |
```

Y ejecuto la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
select json_build_object(datetime, value) as mDatos
from (
    select 
        extract(epoch from (datetime::timestamp))::numeric::integer as datetime, 
        value
    from data_1_4_2018_12 
    where resource_id='s2'
)datos
```

Con lo que obtengo:

```
| mDatos                       |
+------------------------------+
| {"1543837080":4.5}           |
| {"1543837120":44.5}          |
```

Y lo que me gustaría obtener es:

```
               mDatos
-----------------------------------------
{
    "1543837080":4.5,
    "1543837080":4.5
}
```

Ahora mismo me estoy centrando en la parte de los datos pero quiero obtener un JSON mucho más completo. Esta es la parte que me falta. La idea es conseguir crear finalmente un JSON como el siguiente tras consultar otras tablas:

```
{
    "etiqueta":"Sonda temperatura habitación 1",
    "nombre":"s2",
    "datos":
    {
        "1543837080":4.5,
        "1543837120":44.5
    }
},
{
    "etiqueta":"Sonda temperatura habitación 3",
    "nombre":"s3",
    "datos":
    {
        "1543837080":10.5,
        "1543837120":6.7,
        ....
        ....
    }
},
{
    ....
}
```

¿Me podéis echar una mano en sacar la consulta SQL para Postgres 9.4?

Hay una pregunta "parecida" ya formulada: **¿Como puedo hacer un sql que contenga un array de objetos y que esos objetos contengan 2 datos de columnas?** Me ha saltado el mensaje de pregunta "duplicada" pero quería aclarar por qué considero que son diferentes. Mi problema es que no sabía cómo crear un objeto json cuyos valores de "clave-valor" fueran los registros de la tabla. En esa pregunta querían saber cómo obtener un array de objetos json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay funciones que sirven para agregar en formato JSON:

[`json_agg(value)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html) creando un array,

[`json_object_agg(name, value)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html) que te crea el objeto con los atributos agregados:

```
select json_object_agg(datetime, value) as mDatos
from (
    select 
        extract(epoch from (datetime::timestamp))::numeric::integer as datetime, 
        value
    from data_1_4_2018_12 
    where resource_id='s2'
)datos
```

Comment: Creo que también sería útil `row_to_json` pero no estoy seguro

Comment: No me serviría, esto me devuelve un array de objetos json del tipo `[{"1543837080":4.5},{"1543837120":44.5}]` no exactamente en el formato que yo quería. He estado leyendo la documentación y probando varias opciones sin éxito.

Comment: @Jonathan Tienes razón, por eso he añadido json_object_agg a la respuesta

Comment: ¡Esta segunda opción es perfecta! Muchas gracias.